# default(T) return null where T inherits from DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, generics

My sample code:

```
public class GenericClass<T> : IDisposable where T: System.Data.Linq.DataContext 
{
    public T context{ get; private set; }       

    public GenericClass()
    {
        this.context= default(T); // default(T) return null
        // code
    }       

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Using the GenericClasss sample code:

```
using (GenericClasss <DataAccessDataContext> dataAccess = new GenericClasss <DataAccessDataContext>())
{
  //code
}
```

where `DataAccessDataContext` is a .dbml (inherits System.Data.Linq.DataContext) and have default constructor

Sorry if it's something simple and I do not notice. Thank you very much.

Comment: what were you expecting ?

Comment: That's what `default` is supposed to do. What were you expecting, or trying to achieve?

Comment: Whats your question/problem?

Comment: sorry the confusion, I need the "new" of T

Comment: Mabe learn the langauge then? Default of any reference type is null. That is fully defined in - ah - the langauge specifications.

Comment: @Nacho The confusion might be that you don't constraint your generic type. You could add the `new()` constraint to force your generic to have an empty constructor, if that's what you need. `where T: System.Data.Linq.DataContext, new()`

Comment: excuse my confusion, thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wan't to be able to create a new object from generic type, you should use the `new()` keyword:

```
public class GenericClass<T> : IDisposable where T: System.Data.Linq.DataContext, new()
```

And call `new T()` inside your constructor:

```
public GenericClass()
{
    this.context = new T();
}
```

The compiler must know the `T` have a default constructor.

Comment: If you need to call a non default constructor (such as one with a connection string parameter) you can use Activator.CreateInstance, since the new() generic constraint only applies to the default parameterless constructor.

Comment: Yes, or you could use another approach if you need a better performance: http://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/dont-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions/

Answer (score 6):

This is the expected behaviour for the default value of a reference type, the `default(T)`, where `T` is a reference type is `null`.

Comment: sorry for my confusion, thank you very much

Comment: @Nacho you welcome dude ! Not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to instantiate a new context, you could do this:

```
public GenericClass()
{
    this.context = new T();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the class with the generic `new()` constraint:

```
public class GenericClass<T> : IDisposable where T: System.Data.Linq.DataContext, new()
{
    ...
```

and use

```
this.context = new T();
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx